# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<xxx>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<xxx>

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am getting the following error. I googled it for more than a day but I cant find the exact solution, Please help me Thank you

> ERROR: Cannot implicitly convert type
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<ADCO.eJMC.EntityDataModel.ShareholderUser>>`
>   to
>   `System.Collections.Generic.List<ADCO.eJMC.EntityDataModel.ShareholderUser>`

I used the following code

```
List<ShareholderUser> list = new List<ShareholderUser>();
list = dataContext.EJMCShareholderApprovals
                  .Include(s => s.Shareholder.ShareholderUsers)
                  .Where(e => e.EJMCRequestId == requestId)
                  .Select(s => s.Shareholder.ShareholderUsers
                                .Where(x => x.AccessMode == true))
                  .ToList();
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The problem is that at the moment, you're selecting a sequence of sequences - one sequence of ShareholderUser items for each Shareholder. If you just want a list of ShareholderUser items, you need to flatten the results. That's most easily done using `SelectMany`, which can actually replace your `Select` call in this case.

```
List<ShareholderUser> list = dataContext.EJMCShareholderApprovals
                                 .Where(e => e.EJMCRequestId == requestId)
                                 .SelectMany(s => s.Shareholder.ShareholderUsers)
                                 .Where(x => x.AccessMode == true)
                                 .ToList();
```

Note how breaking the query over multiple lines makes it much simpler to read, too. Also, there's no point in initializing the `list` variable to a `new List<ShareholderUser>` if you're then immediately going to give it a different value. I've also removed the `Include` call, as that was unnecessary - you're explicitly selecting `Shareholder.ShareholderUsers` in the query, so you don't need to include it.

Comment: I think the `.Include(s => s.Shareholder.ShareholderUsers)` line is redundant, because we select `s.Shareholder.ShareholderUsers` anyway: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738708.aspx

Comment: @Kobi: I'll add that as a comment, but I don't know enough about EF to state it confidently...

Comment: You do not need to add the include if you are only using what you are selecting. Only if you want to *include* something specific to the context which otherwise would be lazy loaded.

Comment: Thank you @Jon Skeet. Iam getting the exact output what I need.
and Kobi you are right, .Include(s => s.Shareholder.ShareholderUsers) is redundant.I removed it, Thank you for your comment

Comment: @JanneMatikainen: Thanks. With sree's confirmation, I've modified the answer to remove the `Include` call.

Answer (score 0):

This should do it?

```
var list = dataContext.EJMCShareholderApprovals
              .Include(s => s.Shareholder.ShareholderUsers)
              .Where(e => e.EJMCRequestId == requestId)
              .Select(s => s.Shareholder.ShareholderUsers
              .Where(x => x.AccessMode == true)).ToList();
```

though you are doing select on to ShareHolderUsers? Are you trying to get a list of ShareHolderUsers or a list of lists of ShareHolderUsers?

```
.Select(s => s.Shareholder.ShareholderUsers
```

Comment: That will compile, but I don't think it will do what the OP wants. The fact that they're explicitly specifying a type for `list` suggests that they know what type they want... you've effectively changed the type of `list`, leaving the query alone. I believe the key is to change the query.